# Why $L^p(\Omega) \cap L^q(\Omega)$ and $L^p(\Omega) \cap L^\infty(\Omega)$ are dense in $L^p(\Omega)$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\Omega$ an open set in $R^n$ and $1\le p,q \le \infty$

To prove $L^p(\Omega) \cap L^\infty (\Omega)$ is dense in $L^p(\Omega)$ can I consider the succession $f_n=f_{\chi_{{\Omega \setminus E_n}}}$ with $E_n=\{x \in \Omega: |f(x)|>n \}$?

Let $f\in L^p.$ $f_n \in L^{\infty}$ and $\forall x \in \Omega \quad|f_n(x)|\le|f(x)|$ so for the Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem $||f_n-f||_p \rightarrow 0 $
So I've found a succession in $L^p(\Omega) \cap L^{\infty}(\Omega)$ that converges to an element in $L^p(\Omega)$.

Hoew can I proof $L^p(\Omega) \cap L^q(\Omega)$is dense in $L^p(\Omega)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it seems right, your approximation is in the good space and converges to $f$ in $L^p$ by the Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem.

Since $C^\infty_c⊂L^p∩L^\infty$ you can also use the density of $C^\infty_c$ into $L^p$ (take $\varphi_n∈ C^\infty_c$ converging to $f$ in $L^p$. Then $\varphi_n$ is also a sequence of $L^p∩L^\infty$ converging to $f$)

Comment: It's right my proof up?